# vertical menu in css not formatting correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to show the menu as follows

```
|  HOME  |
|  GAMES |
| PLAYERS|
|SCHEDULE|
```

The problem is that my menu is showing like this

```
|  HOME  || GAMES |
|PLAYERS||SCHEDULE|
```

and also.. how can I set the width of it to be consistent?, right now it takes only the length of the word inside of |HOME| but i would like to set this to a fix number.. I am new to css please help

```
.#tabshor {
    width:100%;
    font-size:50%;
    line-height:5px;
    }

#tabshor ul {
    margin:-30px;
    padding:150px 0px 0px 0px;
    line-height:10px;
    }

#tabshor li {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:5;
    }

#tabshor a {
    float:left;
    background:url("../images/tableft.gif") no-repeat left top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#tabshor a span {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:url("../images/tabright.gif") no-repeat right top;
    padding:10px 20px 20px 10px;
    color:#FFF;
    }

#tabshor a span {float:none;}


#tabshor a:hover span {
    color:#FFF;
    }

#tabshor a:hover{
    background-position:0% -42px;
    }

#tabshor a:hover span {
    background-position:100% -42px;
    }

div#tabshor>ul>li {   
        display:block; 
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        left:50px;
    }

 div#tabshor>ul>li ul{
            position:absolute; display:none;
            list-style:none;
            left:100px;    
        }

 div#tabshor>ul>li>a{
            display:block;
        }

  div#tabshor>ul>li:hover ul{
      display:block;  
      z-index:500; 
      width:50%;
      margin:10px 0px 0px -20px;    
      width:100%;
      }

div#tabshor ul li ul a{
    display:block;
    width: 50px;
}

div#tabshor ul li a:hover{
     background:red;
     font-style: oblique;
}
```

HERE IS THE HTML

```
 <div id="left_banner" class="divleftside">
    <div id="tabshor">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>GAMES</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>PLAYERS</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="PLAYEERS.html"><span>PLAYERS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>SOCCER</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>BASKETBALL</span></a></li>               
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>COURTS</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>REFEREES</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>CONTACT US</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>REGISTER</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML as well? Or if you want a faster answer, try to get the problem into a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yep we need the HTML as well so we know what classes are doing what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1. Remove `float: left` from `div#tabshor>ul>li`
2. Remove `float: left` from `#tabshor a`
3. Add `width: 170px;` to `div#tabshor>ul>li>a`

Cleaning up your CSS might lead to less headaches. Also starting with an example like [this vertical rollover list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical08.htm) or [this nested vertical rollover list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/vertical11.htm) might be easier.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot.. the last issue i have is making the submenu pop up next where PLAYERS is.,.. it is showing underneath of another div... how can i bring it to the top?

Comment: Try removing margin:10px 0px 0px -20px; from div#tabshor>ul>li:hover ul and adding padding: 0; to it.

Comment: It shows but only one item of the list.. is like its collpased :(

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on this subject - perhaps you should look into one. Here are some examples: http://css-tricks.com/2282-simple-jquery-dropdowns/ (using JQuery) - http://ginva.com/2011/04/108-free-css-menu-designs/ - http://www.mycssmenu.com/